# serve ssl webpage via nginx, ssl_error_rx_record_too_long

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, nginx

Please help me:  there is something wrong in this `virtual.conf` nginx conf file that means that when viewing the site, I get the error `ssl_error_rx_record_too_long` rather than being able to view my site.  I am using aws, nginx to serve some rails apps - this was working yesterday, but I crashed my entire server and am frantically trying to fix this at 2am, ready for production at 9:30am.

```
ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/star_my_site.pem;
ssl_certificate_key         /etc/ssl/star_my_site.key;


# ------------------
# rails app one
# ------------------

upstream my_app {
  server unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock;
}

server {
  listen      80;
#  server_name rails_app_one.my_site.com.au www.rails_app_one.my_site.com.au;
  server_name _ localhost;
  return      301 https://rails_app_one.my_site.com.au;
}

server {
  listen   443;
  server_name _ localhost;

  location / {
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
     proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
     proxy_redirect off;
     proxy_pass http://my_app;
  }

  location ~ "^/assets/" {
    root /var/app/current/public;
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }
}

# ------------------
# rails app two
# ------------------

upstream rails_app_two_app {
  server unix:///var/run/puma/rails_app_two_app.sock;
}

server {
  listen      80;
  server_name rails_app_two.my_site.com.au www.rails_app_two.my_site.com.au;
  return      301 https://rails_app_two.my_site.com.au;
}

server {
  listen   443;
  server_name  rails_app_two.my_site.com.au;

  location / {
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
     proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
     proxy_redirect off;
     proxy_pass http://rails_app_two_app;
  }

  location ~ "^/assets/" {
    root /var/app/rails_app_two.my_site.com.au/current/public;
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ssl_error_rx_record_too_long` usually means the server is returning plain HTTP content when the browser is expecting HTTPS content. (You can probably verify this by going to http://your.site:443 and seeing your site.)

You need to enable SSL in nginx - simply declaring `ssl_certificate` isn't enough.

Change `listen 443;` to `listen 443 ssl;`

(Also, I'd suggest putting `ssl_certificate` in the server block, so you can use different ssl certs with other domains.)

Edit: https://serverfault.com/questions/497430/error-code-ssl-error-rx-record-too-long has almost the exact same issue, hopefully you found it before your 9am production release!